# ListView disable vertical scrolling of header view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-mapview, vertical-scrolling

I have a `ListView` with `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView` in its header. When I'm scrolling the list I want the `MapView` to be hidden and it works just fine. But, when I'm scrolling the header from up to down, or down up I don't want `ListView` to perform scrolling - I want it to allow `MapView` to perform its zoom/scroll operations.
I know that it's [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685926/not-able-to-scroll-all-listview-items) to use `ListView`/`MapView` together, but I need to find a solution. I thought about setting the `OnTouchListener` on the `ListView` instance and dispatching its events to the `MapView` when needed but it looks like a not very straightforward solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the end I've solved it by extending the `ListView` class:

```
public class SingleScrollableHeaderListView extends ListView {
    private View mHeaderView;

    public SingleScrollableHeaderListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SingleScrollableHeaderListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SingleScrollableHeaderListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (mHeaderView != null) return mHeaderView.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public void addHeaderView(View v, Object data, boolean isSelectable) {
        if (mHeaderView != null) removeHeaderView(mHeaderView);
        mHeaderView = v;
        super.addHeaderView(v, data, isSelectable);
    }
}
```

The significant part is the `onInterceptTouchEvent()` method - here I'm passing the `MotionEvent` instance to the header view if it exists, otherwise I let the `ListView` to deal with the motion event.

Comment: Thanks for such a nice solution.This is what i was looking for.+1 for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try calling requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true) to the listview when in OnTouch on the MapView